# Scala Error:Type Arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use HIPI to process Image on spark,So i use hadoopfile to creat RDD.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("BundleTest")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val bundle0 = sc.hadoopFile[HipiImageHeader,FloatImage,HibInputFormat]("hdfs://192.168.199.11:8020/Hdfs/Image/image.hib.dat",1000)
```

But I get an error of it.

```
Error:(39, 22) type arguments [org.hipi.image.HipiImageHeader,org.hipi.image.FloatImage,org.hipi.imagebundle.mapreduce.HibInputFormat] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives of value hadoopFile: [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat[K,V]](path: String)(implicit km: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit vm: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit fm: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)] <and> [K, V, F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat[K,V]](path: String, minPartitions: Int)(implicit km: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit vm: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit fm: scala.reflect.ClassTag[F])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)]
val bundle0 = sc.hadoopFile[HipiImageHeader,FloatImage,HibInputFormat]("hdfs://192.168.199.11:8020/Hdfs/Image/image.hib",1000)
                 ^
```

please give me some advises to solve this error.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[`HibInputFormat`](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/javadoc/org/hipi/imagebundle/mapreduce/HibInputFormat.html) extends `FileInputFormat[HipiImageHeader,HipiImage]`, not `FileInputFormat[HipiImageHeader,FloatImage]`. So `hadoopFile[HipiImageHeader,HipiImage,HibInputFormat]` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I have tried it.But it doesn't work.